# How do I get the value of a Realm object before it was changed?

Tags: ios, realm

How do I get the value of an object before it was changed?  It appears realm and object observers are only called after a change is committed with no way to find the previous state.  I'm looking for something equivalent to what Core Data provides with NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification.  I'm using Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: In what language? how will the use case be, subclass possible, etc? what value?

Comment: I'm using Objective-C or Swift.  You should be able to view any value change.  I don't think you can subclass Realm model object.

Comment: Did you check out [Realm Object notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications)?

Comment: Yes, they only get called **after** a change.  I need the value before the change occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you use object notifications, the docs say:

> The block will be called with ObjectChange.change if the object’s properties were changed. The enum will contain an array of PropertyChange values. Each of these values contains the name of a property that was changed (as a string), the previous value, and the current value.

And indeed, the code sample shows how you can access `newValue` and `oldValue`

```swift
token = stepCounter.observe { change in
    switch change {
    case .change(let properties):
        for property in properties {
            if property.name == "steps" && property.newValue as! Int > 1000 {
                print("Congratulations, you've exceeded 1000 steps.")
                token = nil
            }
        }
    case .error(let error):
        print("An error occurred: \(error)")
    case .deleted:
        print("The object was deleted.")
    }
}
```

I also recommend looking at the declaration of `PropertyChange`, inside Object.swift

You will have to register for notifications for each individual object though, you can't get informed of these changes by only registering for notifications from the Realm. So unfortunately it's not as flexible as `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`.